# How to stack functions?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")

base <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-5, 5)), aes(x))

f_sin <- stat_function(fun=sin, colour="red", geom="area", position = 'stack', mapping=aes(fill = "red")) 
f_cos <- stat_function(fun=cos, colour="green", geom="area", position = 'stack', mapping=aes(fill = "green"))

print(base + f_sin + f_cos)
```

Which is producing this graph:

[image]

Why aren't the areas of the two functions stacked?

Comment: I would have expected data to be stacked but functions to be 'added' or 'convolved'. But I really am only commenting on the language and don't know the answer.

Comment: In this context 'added' and 'stacked' are the same, I believe.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa In this context, I would expect "stacked" to preserve the total area between each curve and the x-axis, thus when `f1` is positive and `f2` is negative they would be printed as-is. The answer, I believe, is that stacking is always done *within one layer*, but here you have added the functions as two separate layers.

Comment: Would you be satisfied with using this in a new layer:  `f_sum <- stat_function(fun=function(x) cos(x)+sin(x), colour="green")`

Comment: Hi BondedDust, I get no result when I run `sum(f_sum)`.

Comment: I am sorry for the typo above. I meant to say that I get no graph when I run `print(f_sum)`; I get no error message either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want to do your calculations outside of ggplot.  Is this what you wanted?

```
library(reshape)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(-5,5,0.01))
df$sin <- sin(df$x)
df$cos <- cos(df$x)
df <- melt(df,id="x")
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable)) + geom_area(position="stack")
```

[image]

The red area is sin(x), the green area is 'stacked' (sin+cos).

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but having to build a `data.frame` purposely steals the elegance of feeding a function directly to the graph. From your first sentence I understand that this is simply not possible, correct?

Comment: Never say never. I find that getting to the output (time coding + time running the computer) is faster if I do not resist having a few setup lines prior to the main call. In this case that means defining a data frame before calling ggplot. Often it means defining a function prior to calling one of the looping functions _apply().